# How to generate a password creation link to sent to a Community User?

Tags: community, passwords

When activating a User on our Community, an email is automatically sent to the User's email address, which contains a link for him to set up his password, then access the Community as a logged User.

The problem is that this email is often retained by spam filters and never reaches the User's email box (companies' security policies have been reinforced in the New Normal, and are more and more restrictive with automated emails).

So the question is: **is there a way for a Community admin to generate this password link** and copy it, so as to send it afterwards personally by email and not automatically (e.g. a sales person will send it to his customer directly)? Personal emails indeed have a much higher deliverability than automated ones.

Comment: Your question is an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A more appropriate solution would be to improve email deliverability by [setting up SPF (one click) and DKIM](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354353&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1)

Comment: We've already set SPF and DKIM as recommended... but this is not enough! We need a way to send passwork link personally and not automatically in case automated email never reaches User (it keeps on happening in spite of the actions we took to improve deliverability with SPF and DKIM). Is this achievable?

Comment: Out of the box - no. You can write a custom component that generates the link and lets the end-user see it/copy it.